# CSS height animation on element with dynamic height

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a div with dynamic height, and I want to use animation when the height grows. The problem is that I can't set the div's height (it has to be dynamic), so there's nothing to animate on.

```
.text {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.max {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  height: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/abk7yu34/5/

Note that the shrinking animation works because the div has min-height.

Is there a way to solve this in pure CSS?

Comment: change height:200px to max-height:200px;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `height: 200px;`, so you have both animate for expand and collapse.

Also, use the following to add animate on new line:

```
@keyframes lineInserted {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 20px; /* your line height here */
  }
}
div[contenteditable] > div {
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-name: lineInserted;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
```

```js
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.text').classList.toggle('max');
});
```

```css
.text {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.max {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  min-height:90vh;
}

@keyframes lineInserted {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 20px; /* your line height here */
  }
}
div[contenteditable] > div {
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-name: lineInserted;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="text" contentEditable="true"></div>
<button id="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is dynamic. It's still a fixed height of 200 in .max

Comment: @geoidesic this is a very old post, but I think OP wants a toggleable height, when you click it will expand, click again it collapses.

Comment: Updated to use `90vh`,you could also put anything you want

Comment: @DalinHuang thats literally still a static height.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the max-height attribute on the text class and transitioning to a new (dynamic) min height

```
.text {
    background: green;
    color: #fff;
    transition: min-height .3s ease-in-out;
    min-height: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.max {
    transition: min-height .3s ease-in-out;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Alessi42/abk7yu34/8/

Does this give the desired effect?

Comment: No, now you have a fixed height at 200px again.